# Query Total Time in Rooms by Employee

Tags: sql, sql-server

If I have the following SQL Server table, which contains all security keypad data from employees entering and exiting the building. I am trying to calculate the total time spent in a room

[image]

What functions can be used to find the time spent per entry/exit of a room, so I can then sum up the total time all day per room per user.

Thank you!

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: Rollup but didnt give expected output. though i could have implemented incorrectly.

Comment: Did I ask for code or did I ask for which function should be used?

Answer (score 1):

**1.**
You can convert the entry time and exit time to "minutes after midnight" (which will later be used to count the minutes spent in each room) by using

```
(DATEPART(hour, [Time]) * 60) + (DATEPART(minute, [Time]))
```

**2.** then using `CASE` function, you can create EntryTime and ExitTime columns based on the value under EntryType column.

**3.** After that, you will do a group by User and Room (and day, in case your Time column is of type `datatime`)

Here is the query and a [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/0e2d5/1)

```
SELECT d.[User], d.Room, d.day, 
       (SUM(d.ExitTime) - SUM(d.EntryTime)) as [Time_in_Min]
FROM
(
SELECT
  [User], Room, 
  CASE EntryType WHEN 'Entry' 
    THEN (DATEPART(hour, [Time]) * 60) + (DATEPART(minute, [Time]))
    ELSE 0 END as [EntryTime],
  CASE EntryType WHEN 'Exit' 
    THEN (DATEPART(hour, [Time]) * 60) + (DATEPART(minute, [Time]))
    ELSE 0 END as [ExitTime],
  CONVERT(varchar(10), [Time], 111) as day  
FROM attendance
) as d
GROUP BY d.[User], d.Room, d.day
```

Comment: The idea is solid. That last room session appears to span across midnight so I don't think this will work unfortunately.

Comment: are you referring to the last row that shows negative value? I noticed that, I thought it was due to insufficient data in the sample dataset. In terms of sessions going over midnight, I kind of agree with you, I saw your answer, I like it. Maybe if a pair of exit and enter event gets generated on midnight for tracking purposes... :-)

Comment: Right. Hard to assume since I'm not convinced that's an actual 16-hr stay either.

Answer (score 1):

```
with data as (
    select *, lead("Time") over (partition by "User", Room order "Time" as nextTime
    from T
)
select "User", Room, sum(datediff(minute, "Time", nextTime)) as Duration
from data
where EntryType = 'Exit`;
group by "User", Room
```

This assumes that entry and exit are always paired off and doesn't count a room session in progress. Adjust the calculation if durations can cross midnight and you aren't using a true timestamp. Please explain your requirements and data a bit better to get a more robust solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should try a self join:

```
SELECT a.*,b.[Time] as Exit_Time,
        row_number() Over(Partition By A.[User],A.[Room],A.[Time] Order by A.[User],A.[Room],A.[Time],B.[Time]) as rownum
INTO #Temp
FROM #Table A INNER JOIN #Table B
ON A.Entrytype='Entry' and B.Entrytype='Exit' and A.[User]=B.[User] and A.ROOM=B.Room and A.[Time]<B.[Time]

SELECT *
FROM #Temp
WHERE Rownum=1
```

This would bring the entry and exit time into the same row and it should be easy enough to group the data to get the result you are looking for.

Comment: You could also use the lag function to do this and that will give a better performance